# Razor/WebPages: Using AppState and RequestString in classes

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a regular class I've added to a Razor WebPages to handle some extra database work. To use the data classes, I added `Imports WebMatrix.Data` to the class and all works fine.

I need to access `Request.QueryString` and the `Session` and `AppState` dictionaries in another class. I don't fancy passing in these objects. I've looked around but can't find what classes to import.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always grab it from session, which should still be available even in Razor by doing

```
var ctx = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
var qvar = ctx.Request.QueryString.Get("ABC");
var svar = ctx.Session["XYZ"];
```